# Word 2010 is automatically cropping image being insterted

Tags: images, microsoft-word-2010, paste, crop

Word 2010 is automatically cropping image being insterted like this:

[image]

The million dollar question is why? I have this problem only in this particular section of this document. There is no such problem in another sections of document. The one possibility how to display whole area of image is to use floating layout like the first image in presented screenshot. But this solution has disadvantage that I have to manually format image positions after changes in text before.

P.S.
This is picture format as set by Word after pasting:

[image]

P.P.S.
I replicated this problem in test document and uploaded it [here](http://www.ulozto.sk/xJ1CC6w/word-image-crop-docx). You can test it by copying some image into clipboard and then pasting it into document. Whats interesting, the problem somtimes doesnt appear - it depends on position in document where you insert new image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After looking at the source document I will add a more accurate answer.

The reason for the problem is the image is inline (it is treated as one giant character in the paragraph between other characters). The paragraph that the image belongs has **Line Spacing: Exactly** set (under Paragraph -> Indents and spacing -> Line Spacing). You can fix this problem by changing the Line Spacing value to anything else (such as At Least or Single).

Since the paragraph has exact spacing any glyph which is larger than the line is cut off which is what you see. You may need to fiddle with the image options to position it in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that the image is set to appear behind text and also the paragraphs have a background shading of white which causes the image to be cut off behind the shading.

Changing the ordering or the paragraph background should solve the issue.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I think this is not the case at least the first part of your suggestion (image behind the text).

Comment: You're right. It could well be a bug. Are you able to sanitize the document and upload it somewhere for us to test?

Comment: See updated question for link pointing to test document.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent an hour struggling with this issue. I'm still not sure what causes it, but the way I fixed it is this:

1. Select the problem image
2. Right click, and choose Format Picture
3. Select Crop from the left Navbar
4. Change the crop position height to something LARGER than the picture itself.
5. Watch the instant-preview that Word is doing in the background until the whole image is revealed.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I used Google docs instead of Word and it printed fine. It is certainly a problem with Word 2010. Change your version or use another word editor

Cheers

Comment: Did you read the other answers? Seems to be something that can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and found a solution. My image in a Word 2010 doc was set to In Front of Text and was truncated in the print out. When I do a Format in Picture Tools to change it to In Line with Text, the image came out properly in the print out. I tried some of the suggestions above but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. I tried everything (including things suggested here) and nothing worked. I finally noticed that the paragraph marks on that page (which was a new Section) were in the middle rather than at the right margin (when right-aligned). I went to Columns and selected "One"...in effect, none...voila, fixed!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. Yours is clearly a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was showing up in every Word document.I right-clicked and noticed that the "ungroup" option was available for selection. I ungroup-ed the graphic and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice solution to this problem. Cut the image in the text box by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, then right-click and select "**paste as image**".