# MS Word tables as link from Excel only shows a single line

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, links

I have a Word document that functions as a template using a linked table to an external Excel sheet.
My problem is that when i 'paste special' to insert the link, the table shows only the last line of the table. If I change the layout from 'inline' to another option, the table does show, but whenever I update the link, the formatting is lost.

HAs anyone had a similar problem, and does someone have a way to keep the formatting of a linked table?

Thanks in advance : )

**SOLUTION**

Following the link in the answer, I found that changeing the line-height to **at least** 14px made the whole table appear.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the problem of the chart only showing one line, you are probably experiencing the same issue as asked in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/511873/pasted-image-hides-behind-text-even-when-set-to-be-inline/513450#513450) question.

I hope with this resolved you won't need to update the table and formatting will stay right.