# Pasted images on word does not appears in line with text

Tags: microsoft-word, copy-paste

I paste figures in my word file in many parts of the text and everything looks fine, but in one specific part of text, the figures does not appears in line with text (even selecting this option in the format menu).

See a picture of the file. The figure is "behind" the text:
[image]

I've already tried the solutions in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/511873/pasted-image-hides-behind-text-even-when-set-to-be-inline), but nothing works.

When I change the option in the format menu, the figure appears normally, but the text is spoiled.
The figure is a JPEG file and I'm using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010, version 14.0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to post images to help, so i'll try and describe the best as possible,

1. Right click the image that you're having issues with.
2. Near the bottom of the context menu you should see an option called "Wrap Text", it has an icon with lines and an arch over them.
3. Hover your cursor over this option, and another menu should show itself.
4. Go ahead and hover your mouse over each option until you find the one with the desired effect.
5. Once you have found the one you want, click it and it should change how the text reacts to the image.

You could also use the ribbon to find this option once the image has been selected. I recommend that you play around with word a little bit to get more comfortable.

Comment: If you're having issues with the way the image looks, or it's not being imported correctly. Save the image locally to your computer, then import it into Microsoft Word, rather than copying and pasting.